# Google analytics - traffic from adobe.com

Tags: flash, google-analytics, adobe

We have a flash application https://designer.genomecompiler.com/app  that is getting a lot of traffic from adobe.com/apollo  . It does not make sense, seems like a huge percentage of our users are coming from that url.

Our guess is that it has to do with the fact that the application runs with flash player however we don't have a clue on why. Any ideas on why we are getting traffic from there?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Apollo is the old name for Adobe Air.  This referrer issue is not uncommon and appears to be quite old (references to it on Google since 2009).

e.g https://forums.adobe.com/thread/429383?tstart=0

Probably worth making sure your Air application uses the very latest SDK to ensure its been resolved.